# Отправка сообщений в комментарии Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как возможно реализовать такую логику на **питоне** с **aiogram**?:

Бот заходит на канал (например, *@mychannel*) и комментирует недавние записи с включёнными комментариями

Буду **ОЧЕНЬ** благодарен

Comment: Спам-софт пишете? :) Никак, боты не могут "заходить" в канал. Используйте User API

Comment: заказчик хочет) спасибо за совет

Comment: не нашёл такого в доках(

Comment: В каких доках искали? aiogram это Bot API, вам нужен User API

Comment: вот  [ссылка](https://core.telegram.org/type/User)

Comment: С каким заказчиком вы работаете, что не можете отличить API от объекта?

Comment: подскажите тогда, пожалуйста, правильный путь

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/mtproto

Comment: и как мне это поможет?